# sqlite3 query - value retrieval

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
Hi iam using sqlite3 and have following table : 

userId      name        rollNumber  class       section     fingerIdx          
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ------------------
1           ram         1           1           a           Right Thumb Finger
2           ram         1           1           a           Right Index Finger
```

I have the above values in my table . 
My requirement is to get the single result row having both the fingerIdx and all other values except userId like "ram, 1, 1, a, 'Right Thumb Finger, Right Index Finger ". How to get this?

Comment: I think he means that he wants a result like `ram, 1, 1, a, 'Right Thumb Finger, Right Index Finger'`

Answer (score 0):

There is the `group_concat` function which does what you want. See the [description here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html)

**EDIT:**

This query works with MySQL (I don't have a sqlite currently, but it should work the same way):

```
select name, rollnumber, class, section, group_concat(fingerIdx) from so group by name, rollnumber, class, section;
```

Output:

```
+------+------------+-------+---------+-------------------------+
| name | rollnumber | class | section | group_concat(fingerIdx) |
+------+------------+-------+---------+-------------------------+
| ram  |          1 |     1 | a       | RightThumb,RightIndex   |
+------+------------+-------+---------+-------------------------+
```

**EDIT2:**

And by the way: You should over think your table design! There seem to be two entries for the same user, but with different userIds! Better make `user` table `(userid, name, rollnumber, class, section)` and another for the one-to-many relation `user_finger` (or so) with `(userId, fingerIdx)`